# I cannot view file permissions after 14.04 upgrade

Tags: upgrade

I upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 and have the login loop problem.  I have tried to implement the posted askubuntu solutions regarding this problem, but it seems that I have a core problem that prevents me from accomplishing these tasks.
When I login after  Ctrl-Alt-F1, I try to view the file permissions of .ICEauthority and .Xauthority with `ls -1d ~/.*authority`, but only the names of the two files are displayed with no permission information.  I'm an entry level Linux user/student and new to this site, so please consider this when you answer.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: just type ls -l and it will show you the permissions.

Comment: ...and `-l` is the small L, and not the digit 1(one).

Comment: Well this was somewhat embarrassing.  Apparently my core problem was the monkey on the keyboard who typed the number "1" and not the letter "l".  Now I need to fix the login loop problem.  Thank you for the quick response We are Borg and mikewhatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply mistyped the command. Correct is:

```
ls -ld ~/.*authority
```

With the lowercase letter "L" and not the number 1.

An example output on my machine (user "bytecommander") would be:

```
$ ls -ld ~/.*authority
-rw------- 1 bytecommander bytecommander 6286 Nov  4 17:27 /home/alphawolf/.ICEauthority
-rw------- 1 bytecommander bytecommander   54 Nov  4 17:26 /home/alphawolf/.Xauthority
```

You can see the permission strings of the form `-rw-------`.

#### What the symbols mean from left to right:

`-` it's a file. Directories would have a `d`.

`r` the owner user has read access. (no access would be `-`)
`w` the owner user has write access. (no access would be `-`)
`-` the owner user has *no* execute permission. (permission would be `x`)

`-` the owner group has *no* read access. (access would be `r`)
`-` the owner group has *no* write access. (access would be `w`)
`-` the owner group has *no* execute permission. (permission would be `x`)

`-` all others have *no* read access. (access would be `r`)
`-` all others have *no* write access. (access would be `w`)
`-` all others have *no* execute permission. (permission would be `x`)

There are some more complicated permissions like SUID, SGID or Sticky Bit, but you will very probably not encounter them there.

#### How `~/.Xauthority` has to be configured:

It needs to be owned by your user and its primary group (same name). In the `ls -ld` output, the owner is displayed in the 3rd column (in my example "bytecommander") and the owning group in the 4th column ("bytecommander" as well in my example).

If you find e.g. `root` in both of these columns, you need to change that by running:

```
sudo chown $USER: ~/.Xauthority
```

The permissions should be set up so that only the owning user has read and write access, everything else is denied. If your permission string looks any different than `-rw-------`, you should run the following command to fix it:

```
chmod 600 ~/.Xauthority
```

Note that `600` is the octal representation of the permissions described above. Run `man chmod` if you want more info.